# ¿Cómo usar Sass con vue-cli y webpack-simple?

Tags: nodejs, vue.js, webpack, sass

Quisiera poder crear los estilos de cada **componente** con Sass mientras uso `vue.js` en vez de usar `<style lang="scss"></style>`.

A lo que me refiero es: tener los estilos de cada componente en un archivo `.scss` (ubicados en la carpeta `src/`) y que a través de **Webpack** los compile y los deje en la carpeta `dist/`.

Algo así:...

[image: Árbol de la carpeta src/]

*Carpeta `src/` y sus hijos*

Comment: tienes que configurar webpack para que compile sass y genere un archivo css el cual mandrás a llamar en el index.html, el navegador no entiende el lenguaje sass. Puedes obtener ejemplos aquí https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/procesamiento-css-sass-webpack.html

Comment: Entiendo. Supuse que tenía que hacer eso, pero pensé que habría otra manera. ¡Muchas gracias!